# Deployment for Angular, mySQL and Spring Boot?

Tags: mysql, angular, spring-boot, deployment

As the title reads I am currently looking for the easiest and most-friendly path to take to deploy my project which uses Angular, Spring Boot and mySQL. I have looked in to a couple of methods, one which involves AWS S3, another using Firebase and a third which uses Heroku. I just wanted to know what the best way to do this was, and if it is better to deploy them separately with different servers, or combine them into one?
There are so many options, but maybe one is less convoluted; I was hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be

1. Build your angular project.
2. Copy the angular's index.html and built javascripts files to Spring
   boot's resource folder.
3. Create a controller to serve the index.html.
4. Make sure your spring boot project is serving the index.html and javascript files.
5. Build jar
6. Create a docker container for your jar with java and mysql
7. Deploy to your favorite service